# Не выводит записи в блоге WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет, ситуация следующая. Есть главная страница, типа лендинга, ее сделала через файл index.php и так же на сайте есть блог, страницу со всеми записями сделала page.php. Добавила записей, вывожу с помощью следующего кода, но вместо вывода записей на страницу выводятся существующие страницы. Поправила в настрайках-чтение установила статическую главную страницу и страницу записей, теперь вообще отображает только главную и все. Не пойму в чем дело, подскажите, пожалуйста

```php
<div class="content-box">
    <?php if( have_posts() ){ while( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ?>
        <div class="blog-img-frame">
            <a class="blog-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(386, 290)); ?>" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <h4 class="blog-text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            </a>
                <p class="block-date"><?php the_author(); ?> - <?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?></p>

                <?php the_content(); ?>
            <div class="blog-buttons">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more
                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </div>

        </div>
    <?php } /* конец while */ ?>
    <?php } // конец if ?>
</div>
```

Comment: а где у вас WP_Query() ?

Comment: поставьте себе плагин `Show Current Template` и посмотрите где какой шаблон используется. Когда вы указали страницу для записей для нее стал использоваться шаблон `index.php` а для главной страницы `page.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5'); ?>
<div class="content-box">
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ){ while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="blog-img-frame">
        <a class="blog-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(386, 290)); ?>" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h4 class="blog-text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        </a>
            <p class="block-date"><?php the_author(); ?> - <?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?></p>

            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <div class="blog-buttons">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more
                <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        </div>

    </div>
<?php } /* конец while */ ?>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); // конец if ?>
```

Comment: Попробовала данный код, сейчас <div class="content-box"> просто пустой выходит, хотя записи есть в админке

Comment: 'posts_per_page=5' это как я понимаю сколько постов будет выводиться на странице, верно?

Comment: @KatharineKulikova да

Comment: Еще вопрос, если можно) Пытаюсь вывести записи все кроме записей с одной рубрики прописываю следующим образом, но не выходит, не могли бы подсказать?


```php
<?php if( $query->have_posts() & $query->set( 'cat', '-7' )){ while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Вам в wp_query нужно передать параметр category_in и в него передать id категорий которые вам нужны https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query

Comment: нет, мне надо именно исключить категорию одну...если передать через код те которые нужны, то когда пользователь добавит новую рубрику она не отобразится, а нужна динамика

Comment: Ну тогда category_not_in

Comment: получилось, спасибо)